# Java - java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to enter a first name and a surname. The user is allowed to enter a first name with no issue but as soon as space is hit and their surname is entered, it gives me the error mentioned in the title.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice, 
        String name, stuNum;

        do
        {   
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Student Grade System");
            System.out.println("----------------------\n");
            System.out.println("   1) Enter student details");
            System.out.println("   2) Display student grades");
            System.out.println("   3) Display student statistics");
            System.out.println("   4) Display full transcript");
            System.out.println("   0) Exit System\n");
            System.out.print("Select an option [0-4] >> ");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Entering Student Details");
                System.out.println("------------------------");
                System.out.print("   Student name:                               ");
                name = sc.next(); //somewhere here it messes up
                System.out.print("   Student number:                             ");
                stuNum = sc.next();
            }
         }while(choice !=0);
}
```

This is the bare minimum of my code as I am just starting to write it but this issue is preventing me from going further. I've already tried using sc.nextLine(); and changing the variable stuNum to an int variable. Neither works. The full error it gives is as follows:

`java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at Project.main(Project.java:40)`

Comment: try nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: I've stated that I already tried that. However, I will try again. Whereabouts were you thinking to replace it? at both variables? Or just the name variable?

Comment: I just tested your program on my machine and I'm not getting any error (except that there was a ',' after the definition of `choice` instead of a `;`. Are you sure you're showing us the same version you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use extra nextLine to flush the scanner buffer after you have taken students name

```
switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Entering Student Details");
                System.out.println("------------------------");
                System.out.print("   Student name:                               ");
                name = sc.nextLine(); //somewhere here it messes up
sc.nextLine();  // to clean the enter key stored in the buffer
                System.out.print("   Student number:                             ");

                stuNum = sc.nextLine();
            }
```

Comment: Simple enough answer and it worked perfectly. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using next() will only return what comes before a space.That means It won't consume a space. but nextLine() automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.
So, just replace next() with nextline() in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `sc.next()` will not consume the space. So it will read the next token (in this case the lastname after the space) instead of the next thing entered. Try for yourself: when you put in a name enter `Firstname 1` and it will enter student number 1 automatically. Use Scanner's `nextLine()` method to consume the entire line.

You can parse your int choice with `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());`

Comment: Okay. I replaced name = sc.next(); with name = sc.nextLine(); and all that did was place Student name: and Student Number: into one line when I ran it.

Comment: @SlowpPowl I recommend using `nextLine()` for any input for this type of step-by-step program. You can parse the line however you wish to fit any datatype.